# How to add more channels in AJAX chat?

Tags: php, mysql

How can I add more channels to [Ajax Chat](http://frug.github.io/AJAX-Chat/) ?
My problem is that no matter the changes I make in /chat/lib/data/channels.php, the only channel the chat interface shows me is the "Users" one

My channels.php file

```
// List containing the custom channels:
$channels = array();

// Sample channel list:
$channels[0] = 'Users';
$channels[1] = 'Admin';
```

And I always see only Users channel. Why ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the users.php under /lib/data folder and include the following

`$users[1]['channels'] = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);`

In the above 0 to 10 are the channel permissions by the user

Regards
Narayanan